# best way to check arguments of a function in haskell

Tags: function, haskell, arguments

I have a funciton say foo :: [Integer] -> Bool , but it only works if the incoming argument is valid for some criteria, otherwise it should terminate immediately.

```
 foo x | not $ isSorted x = False
       | otherwise = some_recursive_stuff_here
       where
            isSorted ax = ax == sort ax
```

etc.

But I don't want to check invariant every time if it is sorted or not. Is there a good way to deal with that other then introducing another internal function?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can carry around "proof" that your invariant holds by creating a `newtype`.

```
newtype Sorted a = Sorted { fromSorted :: [a] }

sorted :: Ord a => [a] -> Sorted a
sorted = Sorted . sort

foo :: Sorted Integer -> Bool
foo (Sorted as) -> some_recursive_stuff_here
```

If you hide the `Sorted` constructor in a separate module then users of your code will be unable to use `foo` without creating proof of sorting first. They also won't be able to `sort` a `Sorted` so you can be sure it's only occurred once.

You can even support proof-maintaining operations if you like.

```
instance Monoid (Sorted a) where
  mempty = Sorted mempty
  mappend (Sorted as) (Sorted bs) = Sorted (go as bs) where
    -- lazy stable sort
    go :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
    go [] xs = xs
    go xs [] = xs
    go (x:xs) (y:ys) | x == y = x : y : go xs     ys
                     | x <  y = x     : go xs     (y:ys)
                     | x >  y =     y : go (x:xs) ys
```

(This code is available now on Hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sorted)

Comment: +1. Great use of the type system to communicate program semantics and enforce invariants

Comment: In fact, if you make `Sorted` an `Applicative` or `Monad`, then you can created `Sorted` lists inefficiently using: `pure 1 <> pure 4 <> pure 3 = Sorted [1, 3, 4]`

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: How can it be made an `Applicative` or `Monad`?  What is `pure id <> pure (+1)` supposed to be, for example?

Comment: @TomEllis Hmmm.  I think you are right.  I didn't think that through.

Comment: So you could do lexicographic sorts `(Ord a, Ord b) => Sorted a -> Sorted b -> Sorted (a, b)` and `singleton :: a -> Sorted a` (no `Ord` even!), but you can't have `fmap` in `Hask`, it'd need to be in the some subcategory like `Ord b => a -> b`.